# Impossible constraint in ‘asm’ error with kernel FDO

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, arm, compiler-optimization, pgo

I'm trying to compile the aarch64 kernel with FDO. The initial compilation process works fine, however the second phase of using the gcda files (-fprofile-use) runs into error. Any idea, what this would be happening and how to avoid that? kernel version 5.4.17, gcc8.5

```
./arch/arm64/include/asm/jump_label.h: In function ‘hchacha_block_arch’:
./include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:107:38: warning: asm operand 0 probably doesn’t match constraints
 #define asm_volatile_goto(x...) do { asm goto(x); asm (""); } while (0)
                                      ^~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/jump_label.h:38:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘asm_volatile_goto’
  asm_volatile_goto(
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:107:38: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
 #define asm_volatile_goto(x...) do { asm goto(x); asm (""); } while (0)
```

I have seen other issues at Stackoverflow related to this error talking about not optimizing certain portion of codes as a workaround but I'm not sure how to apply (if possible) the same solution to a macro defined in a header file.
Similar steps for x86 work fine, just wondering what could be the issue here.